# GNU Linker - orphan sections and symbol assignment

Tags: gcc, linker, ld

After reading enough documentation about the GNU linker, I feel confused about combining two different concepts regarding implementing custom linker file.

First concept is [*orphan sections*](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Orphan-Sections.html#Orphan-Sections)-

> If there is no output section with a matching name then **new output sections will be created**. Each new output section will have the same name as the orphan section placed within it. **If there are multiple orphan sections with the same name, these will all be combined into one new output section**.
> If new output sections are created to hold orphaned input sections,
> then the linker must decide where to place these new output sections
> in relation to existing output sections. **On most modern targets, the
> linker attempts to place orphan sections after sections of the same
> attribute, such as code vs data, loadable vs non-loadable, etc**. If no
> sections with matching attributes are found, or your target lacks this
> support, the orphan section is placed at the end of the file.

Second concept is about [*symbol assignment*](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Simple-Assignments.html)-

> Here is an example showing the three different places that symbol
> assignments may be used:

```
floating_point = 0;
SECTIONS
{
  .text :
    {
      *(.text)
      _etext = .;
    }
  _bdata = (. + 3) & ~ 3;
  .data : { *(.data) }
}
```

> In this example, the symbol ‘floating_point’ will be defined as zero.
> The symbol ‘_etext’ will be defined as the address following the last
> ‘.text’ input section. **The symbol ‘_bdata’ will be defined as the
> address following the ‘.text’ output section aligned upward to a 4
> byte boundary.**

So, the **bold** explanation regarding orphan sections dictates that is possible that in the above example, the linker will place another output sections after `.text` output section, which means that the **bold** text in the symbol assignment explanation is wrong.

So, is this example can produce undesired value into the `_bdata` symbol if orphan section exist in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer found on *Sourceware* LD documentation inside the [The Location Counter](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Location-Counter.html#Location-Counter) chapter-

> **Setting symbols to the value of the location counter outside of an
>   output section statement can result in unexpected values if the linker
>   needs to place orphan sections**.

```
 SECTIONS {
     start_of_text = . ;
     .text: { *(.text) }
     end_of_text = . ;

     start_of_data = . ;
     .rodata: { *(.rodata) }
     .data: { *(.data) }
     end_of_data = . ; }
```

> **This may or may not be the script author’s intention for the value of
>   start_of_data**.

So it seems that their documentation with the symbol assignment example and explanation should be edited to mention orphan sections, or removed.